# What does "bank shot off someone" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's for the 8th episode of the 4th season of *Better Call Saul*. The context is James and Kim wins a court case by trickery.

> Kim: The phones were genius.
>
> James: [IN NORMAL VOICE] The phones?
>
> Kim: Yeah.
>
> James: Well, the phones were a touch.
>
> This was all you, start to finish.
>
> **Bank shot off the judge**.

Comment: The standard meanings for "bank shot" and "off" and "the judge" are used.

Comment: Could you explain please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we are not supposed to look up dictionary definitions for people as a service. If you look up definitions and you don't understand them, edit your post and include the info you found and explain what it is that you do not understand.

Comment: @Davo, that's a bit mean, considering this is ELL, and the problem is figuring which words belong together. What makes you think the standard meanings of "bank", "shoot off", and "the judge" weren't used? In other words, the bank used a rocket to launch the judge into a stable orbit.

Comment: @gnasher729 I explained the word groupings in my first comment; I explained ELL site policy about what we do and do not answer; and I offered to clarify if the OP would show research and explain what was still confusing (as per site guidelines). Please show me my mistake, so that I can improve my performance.